# nofollow option for rich texts

Tags: redactor, richtext

Is there a way to add an nofollow option to the rich text editor? Just like new window option.
The only thing I found is a Redactor config to make *all* links nofollow. But I need it optional per link.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing native in Craft that would allow you do to that.

Should be possible via a Craft and Redactor custom plugin, though, I'd guess.

Comment: OK, thank you Brad